# How can I get the route that matches a particular route string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

How can I get the Route that matches a particular URL string?

For example, let's say I have a string:

```
/home/index/3487
```

How can I fetch the Route in the RouteTable that would get triggered if this string were to be placed in the URL? I know I need to iterate over the RouteTable.Routes collection, but other than that I am not sure...

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phil Haack at Microsoft wrote a nice route debugger that he blogged about in the past [ASP.NET Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) and updated more recently [RouteDebugger 2.0](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx). The package can be installed using nuget if you have that installed [Route Debugger - 2.1.1](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/routedebugger).

Comment: And if you want to see the source code, it is part of the `RouteMagic` package at http://routemagic.codeplex.com